# Method Not Found Error When Instantiating IntegrationServices Object

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a C# console app that tries to create an instance of a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices object:

```
string SqlConnectionstring = $"Data Source={ serverName };Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlConnection cn = new(SqlConnectionstring);
IntegrationServices ssis = new IntegrationServices(cn); //fails!
```

But when the last line of code runs, the following exception is raised:

{"Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection..ctor(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)'."}

I'm using the SQLServer.SMO.2016 NuGet package for the SMO and IntegrationServices assemblies.

Not sure how to fix this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does `cn` look like after you assign `new(SqlConnectionstring)`; I bet my money that it's not returning a `SqlConnection` object; check your connection string as well. More than likely you want something like: `SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionstring);`

Comment: The DataSource in your connection string is wrong or you do not have the credentials to login to database.  Integrated Security means you are using the user login credentials and the server must allow the user (or user group) access to the database.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio to login to the server to check credentials.  The login window of SSMS gives server name and you should use same in the connection string.

Comment: Data source is correct.  I can connect to the source in SSMS using Windows authentication and run queries.  The SqlConnection variable "cn" is not null after it gets created.  Its State property is Closed but even if I open it prior to creating the IntegrationServices object, the same error occurs.  I'm stumped.

Comment: @Codexer - I did try instantiating the SqlConnection like you suggested.  Still get the same error when the IntegrationServices object tries to be created.